# Failed to start the VM error when starting a Dataflow SQL job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Getting the following error when I try to launch a Dataflow SQL job:

Failed to start the VM, launcher-____, used for launching because of status code: INVALID_ARGUMENT, reason: Error: Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'global/networks/default'. The referenced network resource cannot be found. HTTP Code: 400.

This issue just started today.

Comment: Can you check your VPC network and see if network `default` is still available?

Comment: The `default` network is not there in the project that I am getting the error from. When I tried it in another project that had `default`, it seems to be working. Thank you! I am not sure what sets up this `default` network though.

Comment: The default network is available when you first time created the project. It's possible someone else has deleted the network configuration. For Dataflow to work, it needs network: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks. You can follow instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#creating_networks to create a new network for this project.

Comment: Or you can check if there is a Shared VPC network created by your organization. If someone from your organization is doing such kind of work, they might have created a host project somewhere for networks, and maybe that's why the default network in this project is deleted.

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `default` network solved the issue.